# Error "Subscript out of bounds" in Shiny, but not in R?

Tags: r, datatable, dataframe, shiny, render

I am working on creating a Shiny app to perform text analytics on resumes. In R Studio everything works fine, but when I try to run the Shiny app, I get an error "subscript out of bounds" for my qualified function (the output).

In R Studio, I run this code, which works fine (you will have to insert a folder of .txt documents in like 1 for it to actually run):

```
cname <- file.path("insert any file of .txt documents")   
dir(cname) 
length(dir(cname))
library(tm)
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname)) 
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/|@|\\|")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords ("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
length(freq)
list<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs,list(dictionary = c("python", "machine")))
relist=as.data.frame(as.matrix(list))
machine = ifelse(relist$machine > 0, 1,0)
python = ifelse(relist$python > 0, 1,0)
as.numeric(machine)
as.numeric(python)
newlist=cbind(machine, python)
totals=rowSums(newlist)
docname=dir(cname)
wordtotals=cbind(docname, totals)
qualified=wordtotals[wordtotals[,2]>=2,]
```

In R Shiny, I have the following code :

```
## ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Resume Text Analysis"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
    mainPanel(h2("Qualified Applicants"), dataTableOutput("table")),
    sidebarPanel(h2("Specifications"),

      textInput("filepath", label = h4("Paste the file path for the folder of '.txt' files you would like included in the analysis.")),

      helpText("Choose up to 10 words that a qualified applicant should have in their resume. These can be skills, programming languages, etc. Please put '' '' on either side of each word."),

      textInput("word1", label = h3("Term 1"), 
                value = ""),
      textInput("word2", label = h3("Term 2"), 
                value = ""),

      helpText("A qualified applicant will have a resume with at least ___ of the terms above."),

      numericInput("morethan", 
                   label = h3("Number of terms required:"), 
                   min = 1, max = 2, value = 1)

  )

)))

## server.R


 library(tm)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$filepath,{
      if(is.null(input$filepath) || nchar(input$filepath) ==0) return(NULL)

      cname <- file.path(input$filepath) 

      dir(cname) 
      length(dir(cname))

      docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname)) 

      toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
      docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/|@|\\|")
      docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
      docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
      docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords ("english"))
      docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)

      one = input$word1
      two = input$word2

      list<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs,list(dictionary = c(one, two)))

      relist=as.data.frame(as.matrix(list))

      one = ifelse(relist$one > 0, 1,0)
      two = ifelse(relist$two > 0, 1,0)

      as.numeric(one)
      as.numeric(two)

      newlist=cbind(one, two)

      totals=rowSums(newlist)

      docname=dir(cname)

      wordtotals=cbind(docname, totals)

      num = input$morethan

      as.numeric(num)

     output$table <- renderDataTable({
       wordtotals[wordtotals[,2]>=num,]
     })

  })

}
)
```

Is this an error within R Shiny (since the code works fine in R Studio) or am I missing something in my coding?

Thanks

Comment: Throw in some `browser()` calls and check out what your objects R inside shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redo your server.R like this, your problem came from trying to access the columns in the datafram with the `$` operator, `df$str` is equal to `df["str"]` where str is a actual column name and not a variable. Try this, this should work for you.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    # Check path input
    if(is.null(input$filepath) || nchar(input$filepath)  == 0) return(NULL)

    # Check if valid
    if(!dir.exists(input$filepath)) return(NULL)
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
      as.data.frame(qualified)
    })

    cname <- input$filepath

    docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname)) 
    toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern, " ", x))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/|@|\\|")
    docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords ("english"))
    docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
    dtm  <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)

    d <- c( input$word1, input$word2, input$word3, input$word4, input$word5, 
           input$word6, input$word7, input$word8, input$word9, input$word10)

    list   <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs,list(dictionary = d))
    relist <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(list))

    res    <- do.call(cbind,lapply(names(relist),function(n){ ifelse(relist[n] > 0, 1,0)}))

    totals <- rowSums(res, na.rm=TRUE)

    docname=dir(cname)

    wordtotals=cbind(docname, totals)

    num=input$morethan

    df <- data.frame("document"=docname,"total"=totals)
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
      df[df$total >= as.numeric(num), ]
    })

  })
}
)
```

Comment: That seems to have partially fixed it! Now when I run the code, I no longer get the error message, but I still don't get an output either. RECV {"method":"update","data":{"filepath":"my folder of .txt files,"word1":"'r'","word2":"'python'"}}
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"word3":"'java'","word4":"'pig'","word5":"'hive'","word6":"'shiny'","word7":"'machine'"}}
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"word8":"'learning'","word9":"'studio'","word10":"'mining'","morethan:shiny.number":4}}                                                  It seems the output isn't being sent back out. Any ideas?

Comment: I am back to "Error in wordtotals[,2]: subscript out of bounds" I will try and scale down my example. How would you include error checks? I have found some code that shows me what is going on as far as what the server is sending/receiving, but that is all I have come across.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this error comes from the `wordtotals=cbind(docname, totals)` part when there are no totals and because of this the matrix has no second column.

Comment: I think it may be that I have the shiny app set up so that the user inputs their terms (word1, word2) as 'python' or 'machine' (because they need to be in quoted in the line list<-DocumentTermMatrix...), but then it is searching my documents for " 'python' " instead of searching for python and then putting it in quotes in the list command. If I had them only input python could I then do list<-DocumentTermMatrix(docs,list(dictionary=c("one","two") or would that make it search for the words one and two instead of using the terms that were input that I renamed one and two? Thank you much!

Comment: I see your problem now, it comes from indexing the data.frame, I updated my answer to fix this. Also I changed the 'observeEvent` to observe so that the code is executed once any of the inputs change (sorry, long day)

Comment: thanks for all your help! The final step was changing renderTable to renderDataTable in a couple spots, but everything is executing perfectly now. (: